# Static UIView changes width when localized to French

Tags: ios, uiview, localization

I have a UILabel and a UITextField embedded in a view (so I can hide the view and make several items dis/appear at once, rather than hiding each one). Here's a screenshot of the thing in action in English:
[image]

When I switch to French and run, I get this:
[image]

which you can see runs the textfield and the label off the right. Only in French, though. German, Spanish, Italian are all fine. I shortened the French text in the placeholder/textfield, but that didn't change anything. Here's a chunk of the storyboard definition:
[image]

The text in the label (Your sound was saved) is centered, the textfield is centered. What could cause the label's length to change so much when localized to French? The label and the textview are not linked; both are trailingEdge defined by the "hiding view". A little more checking - The "hiding view" is wider in French than in the others, by 39 (viewed at the beginning of ViewDidLoad.) By the time we get to the main idle state, waiting for the user to tap the record button, the "hiding view" width has increased by another 191. That accounts for the stretching of the text field and the label, since they're pinned to the right side of the hiding view.
The textfield frame is the same in English and French.
So I guess the question is why the UIView width changes in French, but not English. The code only touches the view to set its alpha to 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the label does not fit text into width defined by constraints it has two ways for its layout:

1. Break *optional* constraints if there are any
2. Truncate the label

Since your trailing constraint is *optional* (priority < 1000) the layout engine breaks it and causes the label to go off screen. So to fix the issue make the trailing constraint to be required (i.e. set its priority to 1000).

Comment: Thank you. It was not clear that the text was too long, but I made the changes you suggested and the problem was solved. The explanation you gave was helpful and will benefit my code in the future, too.